# Slowly decaying sequences are dense in $l^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Consider $S:=\{x \in l^1 : \sup_n|nx_n|=\infty\}$. Show this set is dense in $l^1$.

I am a bit stuck on how to proceed, but I think I managed to simplify this problem slightly.

By Baire category theorem we could show that $S$ is co-meager, and thus it would suffice to show that $C_N:=\{x \in l^1 : \sup_n|nx_n|\leq N\}$ are nowhere dense ($N$ here is a natural number).

It's easy to show these sets are closed. How could I show that their complement is dense, or that they have empty interior?

---

Addendum: do you also have in mind an explicit element of $S$?

Comment: You can pick some element in $x\in S$, vary the sign in the right manner and consider the sequence $y+1/n\cdot x$ which is in $S$ and converges to $y$. So you only need to construct some element in $S$. One example would be $x_{n^2}=1/n^{3/2}$ and $x_m=0$ if $m$ is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } n \neq p^3\\
\frac{1}{p^2} &\text{ if } n =p^3
\end{cases}$$

$\{a_n\}$ belongs to $S$. For $x=\{x_1, x_2, \dots\} \in \ell^1$, consider the $S$ sequence $\{X_n\}$ defined as

$$X_n(m)=\begin{cases}
x_m & m \le n\\
a_m & m \gt n
\end{cases}$$

We have $X_n \to x$ in $\ell^1$ which allows to conclude to the desired result.